# use inner class in a template class where it belong to

Tags: c++, templates, inner-classes

my code

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template<typename E>
struct Node{};

template<typename E,typename I>
class List{
public:
  class Iterator{
  public:
  private:
    ListNodePtr ptr; //‘ListNodePtr’ does not name a type
  };
private:
  ListNodePtr foo(ListNodePtr); // ‘ListNodePtr’ does not name a type
  struct ListNode:public Node<E>{};
  typedef ListNode* ListNodePtr;
};
```

I got error message (comment above)

How can I make it work?

Additionally, I am not sure how to define `ListNodePtr foo (ListNodePtr)` in .cpp

I would really appreciate any help.

Comment: Maybe moving `typedef ListNode* ListNodePtr;` above `class Iterator{` will help?

Comment: You are using struct List , I think it should be class List

Comment: @user1000 There are only 3 differences between `class` and `struct`.  The default access-specifier of members.  The default access-specifier when inheriting from the type.  And the fact that you can use `class` instead of `typename` for template parameters, but you cannot use `struct`.  So, using `struct` there is perfectly fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A type must be known when it is used the first time.
You must change the order of your declarations.

Note, the type `ListNodePtr` has to be known when the class `List::Iterator` is declared, becaus the type is used inside the class.

```
template<typename E,typename I>
struct List{
private:
    struct ListNode:public Node<E>{};
    typedef ListNode* ListNodePtr;
public:
    class Iterator{
        ListNodePtr ptr;
    };
private:
    ListNodePtr foo(ListNodePtr);
};
```

For the structure `ListNode` you can use a forward declaration too.

```
template<typename E,typename I>
struct List{
private:
    struct ListNode; // forward declartion of the structure `ListNode`
    typedef ListNode* ListNodePtr;
public:
    class Iterator{
        ListNodePtr ptr;
    };
private:
    ListNodePtr foo(ListNodePtr);
    struct ListNode:public Node<E>{};
};
```

Comment: Oh it does so,  Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Type declarations should be upper on their usage.

Move your `typedef` before its usage.

[Here](https://godbolt.org/g/PMi1xM) a demo which compiles.

Comment: @FrankWang You can mark it private then. Actually it is a good practice to prefix everything with access specifier instead of grouping by it.